# Block Safari updates

Tags: safari, big-sur

I have been on the public beta of Monterey for a while, and have been dissatisfied with the design of Safari.

The other day, I received a notification on my non-beta computer that Safari 15, which is the same Safari on the aforementioned Monterey, was available for download. Then no matter what I chose on “Software Updates” it would appear again

I’ve tried to use the blocking methods available for pre-Big Sur macOS, but that functionality has been removed (ie `softwareupdate --ignore`).

Is there a way to block Big Sur from downloading the “upgraded” version of Safari?

Comment: Sure.  Turn off automatic updates.